# How to say "respond" in this sentence

Tags: word-choice

What word to use to mean "respond" in the sentence below:

"You should respond to her confession" ー彼女の告白にお**返事**してください

Most accurate I can think of is **返事** but it still feels wrong

Comment: ...and it "still feels wrong" because? https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E5%91%8A%E7%99%BD%E3%81%AB%E8%BF%94%E4%BA%8B%22

Answer (score 1):

You can use 返事 and 返答. 答える is another possibility but it sometimes has a nuance of *accepting*, which you may not want. You can say 彼女の告白に返事をするべきです for example. Note that ～してください means "please do ～", which is different from "should ～".

Answer (score 0):

"Respond" is a little vague here. You can respond to a confession of murder by calling the cops. If the situation is that a woman has confessed her love, and the receiver of said confession is being exhorted to give a spoken answer, then in reality, of course, Japanese people would probably say something like 彼女が告白したんだからなんか言えよ。